# How to exclude cases that do not repeat X times in R?

Tags: r, database-design

I have a long format unbalanced longitudinal data. I would like to exclude all the cases that do not contain complete information. By that I mean all cases that do not repeat 8 times. Someone can help me finding a solution?

Below an example: I have three subjects {A, B, and C}. I have 8 information for A and B, but only 2 for C. How can I delete rows in which C is present based on the information it has less than 8 repeated measurements?

```
temp = scan()
A 1 1 1 0
A 1 1 0 1
A 1 0 0 0
A 1 1 1 1
A 0 1 0 0
A 1 1 1 0
A 1 1 0 1
A 1 0 0 0
B 1 1 1 0
B 1 1 0 1
B 1 0 0 0
B 1 1 1 1
B 0 1 0 0
B 1 1 1 0
B 1 1 0 1
B 1 0 0 0
C 1 1 1 1
C 0 1 0 0
```

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your variable names are `V1`, `V2`... and so on, here's one approach:

```
temp[temp$V1 %in% names(which(table(temp$V1) == 8)), ]
```

The `table(temp$V1) == 8` matches the values in the `V1` column that have exactly 8 cases. The `names(which(...` part creates a basic character vector that we can match using `%in%`.

And another:

```
temp[ave(as.character(temp$V1), temp$V1, FUN = length) == "8", ]
```

Comment: +1 the `ave` solution is nice. I always for get about that guy.

Comment: I know the OP said "eight," but to be cautious, I might use `blahblah >=8`  to make sure nothing rotten happens.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde, `ave` is always fun to use, and in this particular case, the fastest solution too; now sure how it scales on larger datasets though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach:

```
temp <- read.table(text="
A 1 1 1 0
A 1 1 0 1
A 1 0 0 0
A 1 1 1 1
A 0 1 0 0
A 1 1 1 0
A 1 1 0 1
A 1 0 0 0
B 1 1 1 0
B 1 1 0 1
B 1 0 0 0
B 1 1 1 1
B 0 1 0 0
B 1 1 1 0
B 1 1 0 1
B 1 0 0 0
C 1 1 1 1
C 0 1 0 0", header=FALSE)

do.call(rbind, 
        Filter(function(subgroup) nrow(subgroup) == 8, 
               split(temp, temp[[1]])))
```

`split` breaks the `data.frame` up by its first column, then `Filter` drops the subgroups that don't have 8 rows. Finally, `do.call(rbind, ...)` collapses the remaining subgroups back into a single `data.frame`.

If the first column of `temp` is `character` (rather than `factor`, which you can verify with `str(temp)`) and the rows are ordered by subgroup, you could also do:

```
with(rle(temp[[1]]), temp[rep(lengths==8, times=lengths), ])
```

Comment: Could a `Filter` solution that worked only on temp$V1 and used `%in%` inside "["  be faster?

Comment: `temp[ temp$V1 %in% unlist( Filter(function(subgroup) length(subgroup) == 8, split(temp[[1]], temp[[1]]))) , ]`

Comment: @DWin, yeah it is. Looks pretty nasty, though.

Comment: Heh, I didn't post in an answer box. Cannot indent in a comment. It's no more complicated than your answer. The unlist is added but your do.call is dropped.

Comment: @DWin, just making an observation---not a criticism. Thanks for your comment and insight. I wouldn't have considered doing it this way. I guess what struck me as aesthetically unpleasing was the additional two references to `temp` and the additional double brackets. This is trivial, however.

Comment: Mine wasn't really a criticism either. I generally try to work with indices when the problem is subsetting, and I was attempting to convert yours to an index-centric solution.